# How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS in MVC application (IIS7.5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, redirect, https

I need to redirect my HTTP site to HTTPS, have added below rule but I am getting 403 Error when tried using http://www.example.com, it works fine when I type https://www.example.com in browser.

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Below rule? What do you mean?

Comment: I have added rule using "URL rewirte"  module under IIS and that was in web.config.

Comment: Check this detailed article: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-Redirect-HTTP-to-HTTPS-in-Net-MVC-Application

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use the following in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
  if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
  {
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's incomplete, because any `http` in the parameters of the url would be replaced too. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41260494/1280523)

Answer (score 117):

You can do it in code:

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(){
    if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
}
```

Or You could add the same code to an action filter:

```
public class SSLFilter : ActionFilterAttribute {

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection){
            var url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Moving my redirect logic to Application_BeginRequest() resolved an issue I was having where I was trying to do a redirect based on the typed URL.

Comment: The Application_BeginRequest() worked perfectly for me, thanks.

Comment: the code is not very correct: the following url `http://example.com?someParam=http:` will be transformed into `https://example.com?someParam=https:` modifying parameters string, consider using `string url = "https://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;`  (taken from RequireHttpsAttribute which also do the exactly same thing)

Comment: @cloudguy i suggest posting it as an answer

Comment: Wow. I am very grateful to this thread. I googled "RequireHttpsAttribute" and ended up coding a solution that would disable redirects on my localhost dev environment but enable a custom class in production. Here is the thread I started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042763/mvc-permanent-way-to-use-redirects-for-http-to-https-and-turn-off-for-dev-enviro

Comment: If url's params contains an url or some other `http:` in it, it will be converted too. So I think you should just add the s in the 4th position: `Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Insert(4, "s"));`. See my answer

Answer (score 60):

In the `Global.asax.cs`:

**Simple redirect**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection
        && !Context.Request.IsLocal // to avoid switching to https when local testing
        )
    {
        // Only insert an "s" to the "http:", and avoid replacing wrongly http: in the url parameters
        Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Insert(4, "s"));
    }
}
```

**301 redirect: SEO best practice** (Search Engine Optimization)

The `301 Moved Permanently` redirect status response code is considered a best practice for upgrading users from HTTP to HTTPS ([see Google recommendations](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6073543?hl=en)).

So if Google or Bing robots will be redirected too, consider this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection
        && !Context.Request.IsLocal // to avoid switching to https when local testing
        )
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.AddHeader("Location", Context.Request.Url.ToString().Insert(4, "s"));
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be selected answer IMO, not that I expect OP to come back after 5 years.

Comment: @Matthieu Charbonnier   Thanks a lot

Comment: I agree with the post above - this one should be selected answer

Comment: @Matthieu : Why not use [!Context.Request.IsLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @stomy Because I didn't know the `IsLocal` property. Thanks :)

Comment: @MatthieuCharbonnier where is the `Application_BeginRequest()` method called? Mine isn't doing anything...

Comment: Be aware that 301 redirect will persist deep in the browser, so if you ever have to disable SSL for some reason, your users will have issues.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use 
            if (Context.Request.IsSecureConnection || Context.Request.IsLocal) return;

Answer (score 7):

**I have the following ASP.NET MVC rewrite rule in Web.config file:**

You can try this code with web.config file. If your URL is http://www.example.com then it will be redirect to this URL https://www.example.com.

```html
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
             <rule name="http to https" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Good job sir. The easiest way!

Comment: Similar to the one from Deepak, but not exactly the same if you diff them

Answer (score 3):

You could use the RequireHttpsAttribute for simple cases.

```
[RequireHttps]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

As stated in MSDN...

> "Represents an attribute that forces an unsecured HTTP request to be
>   re-sent over HTTPS."

[RequireHttpsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

I'm not sure you'd want to use this to enforce HTTPS across a large site though. Lots of decorating to do, and opportunity to miss controllers.

Comment: does not work if you have childactions (renderaction) ;-)

Comment: Good spot, what does it do in that case?

Comment: Just crash. "Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions. "
"Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions."

Answer (score 3):

**Use this code in web.config file for redirect http:// to https://**

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
   </system.webServer></configuration>
```

Comment: Similar to the one from Manish, but not exactly the same if you diff them

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple. Just add one line in "Global.asax" file as below:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute(true));
}
```

If you would like to apply only server-side, not local side then apply following code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
         GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute(true));
}
```

Hope it will help you :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I did it thusly, since a local debug session uses custom port numbers:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
            {
                Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http://localhost:25885/", "https://localhost:44300/"));
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http://", "https://"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Preferably there would be some way to get the URL and SSL URL programmatically...

Answer (score 1):

To force https only when the website is lunched on the server and ignore it while running the website on your machine for development :

In Global.asax :

You'll need the Application_BeginRequest() method

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
         // .....
    }

    //force https on server, ignore it on local machine
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection && !Context.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("localhost"))
            Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not exactly for OP but for those who could not make it work like me and have come across this (and although I know there is 403 not 404 error in OP), please refer to this answer if you are getting 404 instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6962829/5416602

Please check that you have binding for HTTP port (80) and not only HTTPS port (443) in your IIS

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to add comments, but thought this supplementary info would maybe help somebody.

I implemented the Global.asax idea with the 301 Permanent Redirect, and added http binding to the site in IIS.  It still gave me 403 Forbidden until I remembered to untick "Require SSL" in SSL Settings.