# Azure Active Directory login error (We are receiving a bad request)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using azure active directory authentication in my website I am setting the reply url as follows:

```
https://example.azurewebsites.com
```

and

```
https://localhost:44379
```

When I log in with `http://example.azurewebsites.com`, I get a bad request.

I was expecting to be redirected automatically to

```
https://example.azurewebsites.net
```

but this did not happen. How can I make it work?

Comment: `azurewebsites.com` or `azurewebsites.net`? You have both there now. It's normally `azurewebsites.net`. Azure AD usually gives a detailed error message, does it say anything? Are you specifying the reply URL to use when redirecting to Azure AD?

Comment: Sorry it is azurewebsites.net it is just writing mistake and the detailed message is  The reply address 'http://example.azurewebsites.net/' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application

Comment: Is your app being redirected to Azure AD from HTTP? I had this error when my app was served with HTTP and the redirect set the redirect URI as the HTTP version instead of the HTTPS one mentioned in config. Are you accessing the site over HTTPS?

Comment: yes i am accessing the website using http but it is configurered in the reply url as https and this is the problem

Comment: Then you have to access the website over HTTPS, not HTTP. It's dangerous anyway to run a website with authentication over HTTP.

Comment: Is there any way that redirect me to https when user enter with http ??
that is exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: You can probably find an answer for your framework with a quick Google search. Here is an example for ASP.NET MVC: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4945883/1658906.

Comment: Thanks that solve my issue.