# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS and to a new domain with C# MVC in IIS7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have a rewrite rule in my MVC project to rewrite URL of any HTTP request to HTTPS:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But now I need to redirect all the requests from the original www.company.com to a new url www2.company.com

How can I do that to keep also the original HTTP to HTTPS?

Any Google Analytics change for this new redirect operation?

EDIT:

Examples:

```
http://old.company.com -> https://new.company.com
https://old.company.com -> https://new.company.com
http://www.old.company.com -> https://new.company.com
https://www.old.company-com -> https://new.company.com
http://old.company.com/Account/Login -> https://new.company.com/Account/Login
https://old.company.com/Account/Login -> https://new.company.com/Account/Login
```

Comment: A redirect and a url rewrite are *completely* different things.

Comment: Hi, my understanding of this is that the rewrite rules helps me redirect the requesta, am I correct?

Comment: No, rewrites have literally *nothing* to do with redirects.  You are not correct.

Comment: Ok, what is the main difference?

Comment: A redirect is the server telling the client "don't go there, go to this other place".  A rewrite is the server receiving a request for X, *internally* saying "i'll call X as Y/Z instead", and thereafter (again, *internally*) the server pretends the URL requested is Y/Z.  The client is not involved at all.

Comment: To use an analogy, say you're a post office worker delivering mail.  You see a package for 123 Street St.  Consulting your Post Office rulebook, you see that deliveries to that address *actually* go to 456 Street Rd.  The sender is not notified.  That is a rewrite.  A redirect would be the post office telling the sender "wait, their address changed", then returning the package to the sender so they can send it to the correct (redirected) address.

Comment: Ok, thanks really it's diferent. Would You like to suggest an answer to help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect HTTP to HTTPS in MVC application (IIS7.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945883/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-in-mvc-application-iis7-5)

Comment: @Amy - i understand the distinction you make, but the rule in the OP's original question does accomplish the goal of client redirection **using** a config section that happens to be called "rewrite" (or rewrite rules).  It is a common thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use rewrite rules to handle multiple domains.  Here's an example that includes regex matching on url:

```
<rewrite>
    <globalRules>
        <rule name="Redirects to HTTPS and www.example.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.*(com|net)$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?example2.(com|net)$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </globalRules>
</rewrite>
```

See [this article](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one) for more details on how to achieve what you need.

Comment: I don't see where your answer uses HTTPS at all.  I think you need to re-read the question.

Comment: Hi @SlimGhost, I dont understand your answer applied to my issue, can You help me on this?

Comment: @Patrick sorry, I left off the "S" in HTTPS. Won't this do what you are wanting (redirect http://example1.com and http://example2.com to https://example1.com)?

Comment: and http to https, that is (sorry for bad link formatting in previous comment)

Comment: Hi @SlimsGhost, and this code is valid for requests from https:/ /old.company.com -> https:/ /new.company.com ?

Comment: @Patrick it should work, but I have not tested this particular scenario.  You might have problems with SSL certs if you change what site you serve to the user, but if the cert is for a wildcard domain name (*.company.com) I think it would be ok.