# Redirect request without writing headers immediately

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the `BeginRequest` event of my app, I am checking if the request is http and calling `Response.Redirect` to redirect to https. Here the code snippet:

```
if (shouldRedirectToHttps)
{
    var newUrl = "https:" + requestUrl.ToSchemelessUri();
    httpContext.Response.Redirect(newUrl);
    return;
}
```

This causes some unexpected behavior when the `EndRequest` event executes. That event has code to add response headers (like correlation id, data center information, etc), which fails as the response headers are already written.

I checked the state of `httpContext.Response.HeadersWritten` and it gets set to `true` immediately after the call to `httpContext.Response.Redirect(newUrl)`.

Don't want to rewrite my entire endrequest code every time I call redirect in the request pipeline. Is there a way to redirect without the headers being written until after the EndRequest event fires?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945883/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-in-mvc-application-iis7-5/4945950#4945950) answer? You could redirect to https in an action filter.

Comment: We have some requests not going through controllers, so cant really use a action filter. Thanks for the suggestion though.